# Share enum declaration values with multiple attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to have a class with several attributes that saves weekdays with numeric values.

```
summary_weekday    :integer
collection_weekday :integer
```

I thought I could map the integers to values [using Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) with two declarations:

```
enum summary_weekday: %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
enum collection_weekday: %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)
```

But Rails doesn't accept that, I cannot define the same value twice in the same class.

> You tried to define an enum named "summary_weekday" on the model
>   "QuestionCategory", but this will generate a instance method
>   "monday?", which is already defined by another enum.

How can I solve this?

Comment: I don’t see how this could be possible. The whole point of the enum feature is to provide those shortcuts; what meaning would `monday?` have when it could apply to both `summary_weekday` and `collection_weekday`?

Comment: Why do you need two definitions of the same values?

Comment: You can't define two enum attributes with similar values in them. That's why you get a conflict error message.

Comment: The question is not about "two definitions of the same values", but of multiple fields sharing the same enum type. Boolean is een enum of true/false and we can have multiple boolean fields without activerecord inserting a bunch of mutuially clashing #true? / #false? methods.

Comment: Heads up: the proper enums could happen: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17511

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As of Rails 5.0 you can use the `_prefix` or `_suffix` options when you need to define multiple enums with same values. If the passed value is true, the methods are prefixed/suffixed with the name of the enum.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum verification: [:done, :fail], _prefix: true
end
```

It is also possible to supply a custom prefix.

```
class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum verification: [:done, :fail], _prefix: :verification_status
end
```

Comment: Looks like this is added in Rails 5.

Comment: is already documented here: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html. We'll have `_suffix` and `_prefix` options

Comment: Tested and @MarioPérez is correct, you should use `_prefix` and not `enum_prefix`

Answer (score 7):

What you are looking for cannot be obtained by [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), as it will try to create methods like `object.tuesday?` for both of the *enums*, which is logically wrong.

I recall [DataMapper ORM](http://datamapper.org) to have exactly this kind of support. For ActiveRecord, you will probably have to create *getter* and *setter* methods manually for these properties and map it there, like:

```
WEEKDAYS = %w(monday tuesday wednesday thursday friday saturday sunday)

def summary_weekday
  WEEKDAYS[read_attribute(:summary_weekday).to_i] 
end

def summary_weekday=(value)
  write_attribute(:summary_weekday, WEEKDAYS.index(value.to_s))
end
```

The code above may need some mangling while typecasting etc. I know that this is not a generic proof and I will really love to know any better solution for this interesting problem; will certainly be very useful.

Courtesy - [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/145275)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In case people are still looking for a solution for Rails 4, I just tried this the other day and it seems to work well.
I need a similar system to work because of various checks an admin must do on an object.
I solved it by creating a Model Concern and using the class method in the Model:

In models/concerns/review_states.rb

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module ReviewStates extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    REVIEW_STATES = {not_initiated:0, in_progress:1, completed:2}
    SIGNUP_STATES = {pending:0, activated:1, disabled:2}
    def prefix_review_states(prefix)
      Hash[REVIEW_STATES.map { |k,v| [k.to_s.prepend(prefix).to_sym, v] }]
    end
  end
end
```

In your model:

```
class ModelName < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ReviewStates

  enum one_status: prefix_review_states("one_")
  enum two_status: prefix_review_states("two_")
```

This seems to make all of the correct database queries.

Good luck!