# Map integers 0-6 to weekday names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a class with two attributes saving weekdays with numeric values. I had hoped to be able to use [Enum](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html), but [appearantly you can not use the same value for two attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23712485/share-enum-declaration-values-with-multiple-attributes) with Enum.

How could I represent the integer value of an attribute to the corresponding weekday?

```
0 => "monday"
4 => "friday"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Date::DAYNAMES[(i + 1) % 7]
```

where `i` is your integer

```
2.0.0-p247 :001 > Date::DAYNAMES[(0 + 1) % 7]
 => "Monday" 
2.0.0-p247 :002 > Date::DAYNAMES[(4 + 1) % 7]
 => "Friday" 
2.0.0-p247 :003 > Date::DAYNAMES[(6 + 1) % 7]
 => "Sunday"
```

You cannot do a straight look up on the index because in `DAYNAMES` 0 is Sunday and you want 0 to be Monday.

Comment: You are just amazing!

Comment: You might answer this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23721968/access-object-attribute-inside-module i guess they both are same.