# Access object attribute inside module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a class with the attribute `.weekday` saved as an integer value.

I'm trying to create a method in a module that converts that numeric value to the corresponding weekday.

This is how I like to work:

```
MyClass.weekday
=> 2
MyClass.weekday.my_module_method
=> "Tuesday"
```

Is it possible to do this conversion with a module method or am I thinking wrong here?

I can access the object from within the module mehtod, by `self`, but I don't seem to be able to do `self.weekday`.

Comment: You want `2.my_module_method` to return `"Tuesday"`?

Comment: There is a `wday` to get the integer value of a day.Like this example `DateTime.parse("Tuesdayy").wday #=> 3`. And if you want the day,just use `yourdateObj.strftime('%A')`.No need of these conversions.

Comment: Not clear. Post the def initions. For instance in a module self could be the module itself.

Comment: Just define on your model, `def dayname Date::DAYNAMES[weekday] end` and on call attribute with `dayname`

Comment: Do you mean the ISO 8601 weekday? Even so, there are two versions: Sunday = 0 (U.S. and some other strange countries) and Sunday = 7 (The whole rest of the world). It is not clear what you want.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4044574/how-calculate-the-day-of-the-week-of-a-date-in-ruby

Comment: What you're trying to do is impossible, instead read about Rails helpers.

Comment: I was perhaps naive, but I though it would be possible to process an attribute much like the approach with Inflector methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is certainly possible. You are correct when you point to ActiveRecord::Inflector as something that works similarly. This approach modifies the `Fixnum` class itself to add new methods and although I don't generally recommend ad-hoc patching of core classes, you can see it in action in `active_support/core_ext/integer/inflections.rb` :

```
require 'active_support/inflector'

class Integer
  # Ordinalize turns a number into an ordinal string used to denote the
  # position in an ordered sequence such as 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th.
  #
  #  1.ordinalize     # => "1st"
  #  2.ordinalize     # => "2nd"
  #  1002.ordinalize  # => "1002nd"
  #  1003.ordinalize  # => "1003rd"
  #  -11.ordinalize   # => "-11th"
  #  -1001.ordinalize # => "-1001st"
  #
  def ordinalize
    ActiveSupport::Inflector.ordinalize(self)
  end
end
```

In your case I might do something like:

```
module WeekdayInflector
  def weekday
    Date::DAYNAMES[self]
  end
end


class Fixnum
  include WeekdayInflector
end
```

which will at least help others track down the methods you added by looking at the module. Please note that this will affect ALL instances of Fixnum and could lead to conflicts if you include a Gem that tries to do the same thing. It is worth asking whether this tradeoff is worth it or if defining a simple view helper is the better way to go.